# Divergence in the number of observations between "Show Feature Count" and Attribute Table using QGIS

Tags: csv, import

I have a CSV file with 187.533 observations. They are points, violence events with their latitude and longitude. I import the CSV to QGIS (version 3.20.1). When I clicked to "Show the Feature Count" appears 175.896 observations. However, when I put the attribute table, it appears 187.533, the original number of observations.

I attach two screenshoot of what I am saying.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what can be happening or the reason of this divergence?

To give you more information, when I do an "attribute by location with a shapefile which divides my Africa in 0.5x0.5 degree latitude, I obtained as a result 182.989 observations which makes sense if the observations are 175.896 and not 187.533.

Update due to a comment:

[image]

Comment: What is exactly an active filter and how can I check if I have it? From what I know, I can do filters in the attribute table

Comment: One possibility is that some of your coordinate are wrong or missing so QGIS import the whole table (you get 187.53 row) but can only display the row with correct coordinate so you get less feature appearing on the map (in your case 175.896). You may want to check your coordinate (look for missing value, wrong decimal separator, text character or out of bound coordinate for your projection,...)

Comment: Thank you @J.R I am trying to discover what can be wrong with my coordinates in that missing observations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Quick solution for importing CSV with all geometries

When loading your CSV, be sure to set semicolon `;` as only delimiter and select double quotes `"` for `Quote` to ignore semicolons inside a text string ("quote"). Otherwise, they are mis-interpret as field delimiters. See below for more details.

### What the difference means

The difference can be explained that in the layers panel, you have the number of **geometries**, whereas in the attribute table, you have the number of **features**. That means: not all features could be correctly generated as geometries. Identify the values in lat/lon column that are problematic. Seems to be connected to [your earlier problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/418879/88814).

See this simple example: one point without lat/lon value was not generated as a point, thus you have three points, but still 4 features:

[image]

### Understand why loading the CSV does not create geometries for all features

You loaded your CSV with empty field for `Quote` in the `File Format` section of the Data Source Manager. However, you should fill in a double quote `"` in each of these fields. Why?

Have a look at your CSV where you have lines like this one here:

```
894;ZAM1104;1104;14-dic-16;2016;1;Protests;Peaceful protest;Protesters (Zambia);"Health Workers (Zambia); Teachers (Zambia)";6;;;0;60;Southern Africa;Zambia;Lusaka;Lusaka;;Lusaka;-15.4169998168945;28.2830009460449;1;Zambia Reports;National;Doctors at the University Teaching Hopsital are commencing a 10-day sit-in protest to bring attention to unfilfilled commitments by the government;0;1567465455
```

Colum no. 10 looks like:

```
"Health Workers (Zambia); Teachers (Zambia)"
```

You see that you have a semicolon `;` as part of the string **inside** this field. However, normally, the semicolon in this file works as a delimiter for fields - that is what we told QGIS when importing: when it finds a semicolon, interpret this as the end of the field and put what follows to the next field (column).

However, in the case here, the semicolon is part of a text string - the text is marked with double quotes `"`. So we have to tell QGIS to ignore all semicolons inside `quote` statement with `"`: where there is a `;` quoted inside a `"` text string, don't use it as a delimiter, but just render it as part of the text string.

Thats why you have to define the `"` in the import dialog:

[image]

### What went wrong in your case

When you import the CSV without that, everywhere where you have a semicolon inside a double quote, it is wrongly interpreted as delimiter and the fields are shifted to the right. So in these cases, the lat/lon fields are not correct any more, just `NULL`. Like this, no point can be created.

Go to the layer with the wrong number of points, draw a rectangle with the  the `Select features by Area` tool and select all features on the map canvas. Then open the attribute table, invert the selection and bring all the selected features to the top. Then you see all the features that are not rendered as points (have a look at the next screenshot).

In the field `assoc_actor_2` you have a text string starting with `"` and this text is "dismembered" where there was the `;` and continues in the next field `inter2` - in some cases (with two semicolons in the text), it is even shifted twice until the final `"`. So fields for `latitude` (and `longitude` as well where you had two `;` inside double quotes) are empty.

*Selected (blue) features with wrong lat/lon values; white features are correctly interpreted:*
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Babel for your help. From what I understand of your comment, 11.637 points are not correctly generated by geometry (187.533 - 175.896), that is, there is a problem with the latitude and longitude in 11.637 observations (points). However, it's the same database that I sent to you in my earlier post and I am doing what you told me (importing with custom delimeters and just marking semicolom). Hence, the problem is still there, right? At the end, it's the same problem.

Comment: If I load the file you uploaded here: drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/Oc89YsKTHfKVl3U with the method described, I get 187532 geometries, see. Please try again and follow the steps as desribed in the other solution. See again here how to do it and the result I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfuN6.png

Comment: Maybe I am stupid or something but I think I am doing exactly that. I have uploaded a screenshot of how I import and the number of observations I obtain (175.896).  Maybe the version of QGIS? I have uploaded in my first comment in this post.

Comment: I'm not sure: do you really use the same dataset or have you modified it? If you download it again from the link above, still the same problem?

Comment: I now saved the loaded CSV as geopackage and uploaded it here: https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/Oc89YsKTHfKVl3U Download the geopackage and open it in QGIS, so you should get all points.

Comment: It's exactly the same dataset. I have not done any modification at all. I am completely sure. In fact, there are the 187.532 observations. The only difference from your screenshot and the mine that I see is what you put in "Quote" and "Escape", what that symbol exactly is?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have donwloaded the geopackage and now I have the 187.532 observations. However, I would like to know what is going on when I do it by myself. Could it be the different that I mentioned to you in my last comment with respecto to "Quote" and "Escape" boxes?

Comment: Indeed: when I leave empty  "Quote" and "Escape" fields when loading the CSV, then I only get 175896 points loaded, wehereas in the attribute table, there are still 187532 features.

Comment: I hope that solves the problem.... what exactly you write in "Quote" and "Escape" I do not see well from your screenshot.

Comment: Double quotes: `"`. See updated answer for a detailed explanation for that.

Comment: Thank you so much Babel, it really helps me to solve my problem and to understand about QGIS. Thank you again for your time, I really appreciate it!.